# Install postgres on Ubuntu18 on AWS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04, offline

I need to run a shell script on my new Ubuntu machine in AWS which has the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

But, due to some restrictions, I don't want to go to internet to do that. So, I downloaded the below two .debs and scp them to the box.

```
postgresql_12+213.pgdg18.04+1_all.deb
postgresql-contrib_12+213.pgdg18.04+1_all.deb
```

And , in the shell script, I replaced the above command with the below:

```
sudo dpkg -i postgresql_12+213.pgdg18.04+1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i postgresql-contrib_12+213.pgdg18.04+1_all.deb
```

Now, while executing the script, i got the below error:

```
(Reading database ... 56588 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack postgresql_12+213.pgdg18.04+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql (12+213.pgdg18.04+1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql:
postgresql depends on postgresql-12; however:
Package postgresql-12 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package postgresql (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-contrib.
(Reading database ... 56591 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack postgresql-contrib_12+213.pgdg18.04+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql-contrib (12+213.pgdg18.04+1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-contrib:
 postgresql-contrib depends on postgresql-contrib-12; however:
  Package postgresql-contrib-12 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package postgresql-contrib (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
postgresql-contrib
```

So, I tried to individually run the below command (just to check, as they work perfectly fine on my local ubuntu machine) which I believe goes to the internet:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

I get the below error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
postgresql-contrib is already the newest version (12+213.pgdg18.04+1).
postgresql is already the newest version (12+213.pgdg18.04+1).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql : Depends: postgresql-12 but it is not installable
postgresql-contrib : Depends: postgresql-contrib-12 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I am not very good with linux, but in the error above, I see it says that postgresql is already on the newest version. But when I try to run the below commands, they dont work:

```
postgres --version
postgres -V
locate /bin/postgres
psql --version
```

It seems postgres is not pre-installed on the machine. So, my issue here is I need to run the below command without internet access ( for which I downloaded the deb and tried but didnt work)

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your ubuntu and then install the packages again -

```
sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

Then install postgresql -

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib -y
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: As I said, I’m doing a POC for a server which won’t be having access to the internet, so I would need to push all the installers there manually. So I can’t try to update the Ubuntu .